# Full Ubuntu 16.04 install on USB flash drive super slow

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, usb, flash

I installed a full ubuntu on a flash drive. At the moment I have the problem that my full Ubuntu install on a fast flash drive (Cosair Voyager 128GB) is very slow. Before the 128GB one I used a 32GB Cosair Voyager and it was booting very fast, fluent workflow, overall great experience. Now I wanted to install a full Ubuntu 16.04 on a bigger drive for more space but it lags very badly. I used the same steps for installation (dd ubuntu image on another flash drive and then full install on Voyager 128GB) and tried many different installation routes like BIOS vs UEFI boot, swap partitions, formating and partitioning with gparted etc. but I can't reach the performance from my 32GB stick (at least 10x slower with lots of freezing).

Are there any things I can try? If I clone the Ubuntu system from my 32GB stick to the 128GB stick it is also very slow. I also tested the read/write speeds for the 128GB stick with writing 0 on the stick which are very good.

Comment: Nowadays Ubuntu will mostly run in RAM. How much RAM do you have? Try the drive on another computer.

Comment: I have 32GB RAM so this shouldn't be the problem. Is it possible that the feature of running in the RAM is disabled?
I tried the drive on different computers.
Thank you for your input